# Wireless 2915ABG not working on a Dell XPS M140

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

i installed ubuntu 11.10 and i am trying to connect my laptop through wifi. but the wireless isn't working. my wilreless is:

`Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2915ABG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)`

My laptop is a Dell Xps M140

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 on my Dell Studio XPS with an Intel wireless card. Network traffic was very slow, down to barely a trickle.

[Resolve slow connexion when using wifi in ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot and LinuxMint11](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1785-resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal) suggests disabling IPv6 or ath9k hardware encryption, but neither resolved the issue.

A couple of comments did the trick for me, however.

> DCL
>   2011-10-15 00:42:13
>
> FYI, Ubuntu 11.10 seems to have a bug in regards to 802.11n. These methods didn't work for me and I actually had to turn N off at my router. It's a high priority bug right now...
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/836250

---

> Douby
>   2011-10-15 08:56:36
>
> 1 & 2 didn't work for me but this did:
>
> ```
> sudo rmmod -f iwlagn
> sudo modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
> ```
>
> bug with n wifi
>
> make this permanent:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn-disable11n.conf
> ```
>
> add
>
> ```
> options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
> ```
>
> save & quit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in all distributions of Linux I tried recently.

Finally this was the answer, but instead of `iwlagn`, I put in `iwl4965` in my WiFi-Driver.