# Unable to connect to secure wifi - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS keeps asking for password

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a TOSHIBA Satellite A80 that originally ran Windows XP. I'm trying to connect it to my home network, secured with WPA2 Personal.

I have checked that I have entered the password correctly, but it keeps prompting me  for it. In between prompts it appears to have connected, but web pages  and other Internet-requiring content will still not load.

I'm aware that a similar issue has  been posted multiple times on this and other forums but any of  the solutions I've seen will not work for me. Could anyone help me out? Thanks.

---

```
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2915ABG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4223] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2915ABG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:1040]
    Kernel driver in use: ipw2200
    Kernel modules: ipw2200
06:04.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx21/x515 Cardbus Controller [104c:8031]
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Go to the `Edit Connections...` menu item in the network icon, and delete any scripts for the wireless network that you're trying to connect to. You may find multiple copies of this script named _1, _2, etc. After you've deleted all of them, try and connect to that wireless network again. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Deleted the saved connection. Now I'm being told 'Device not ready' in the menu.

Comment: @TheoC either restart the Network Manager, or just reboot the system, and retry the wireless.

Comment: @heynnema Restarted and reconnected but it still doesn't work and prompts again and again for password.

Comment: We'll let @Pilot6 finish his train of thought then.

Comment: I don't know anything about this adapter.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/66873/wireless-2915abg-not-working-on-a-dell-xps-m140 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1605848 and

Comment: @bodhi.zazen First link: No such file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn-disable11n.conf`. Second link, response #6: `sudo: rnmod: command not found`

Comment: first link - make the file. second link should be rmmod i think. I do not know the answer, or I would give it to you. you may need to google a bit.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen First link: Nothing happens. Second  link: rmmod complains about no such file or  directory. and can't remove ndiswrapper.

Comment: First link - did you reboot ? If ndiswrapper is not loaded keep going